# How can i fix segmentation fault in my code and what is the process I should follow to fix this in the future?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I'm a beginner to C and came across a segmentation fault, which is what I understand as to be the program trying to access restricted or unavailable area of memory.

This issue is occurring for me in a function:

```
void process_command(struct pizzeria *the_pizzeria, char *command) {
    if (command[0] == 'n') {
        struct order **last_next_order_field = get_last_next_order_field(the_pizzeria);
        *last_next_order_field = create_order();
    }

    if (command[0] == 's') {
        //Line below receives error
        get_integer_input(the_pizzeria->selected_order, "");
    }

}
```

which is linked to this other function:

```
void get_integer_input(int *variable, char *prompt) {
    printf(prompt);
    scanf("%d", variable);
    getchar();
}
```

It must be noted that these functions are relating to this struct:

```
#define PIZZERIA_NAME_LENGTH 16
#define PIZZERIA_OWNER_LENGTH 16

struct pizzeria {
   char name[PIZZERIA_NAME_LENGTH];
   char owner[PIZZERIA_OWNER_LENGTH];
   int selected_order;
   struct order *orders;

};
```

I don't understand why when passing `the_pizzeria->selected_order` in `get_interger_input` in the function `process_command` makes pointer from integer without a cast as in my past functions of getting a char input instead I use the same process and don't receive an error.

I also set variable as a pointer so I don't understand the note produced by the terminal:

> note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
>
> void get_integer_input(int *variable, char *prompt)

Comment: `int selected_order;` That is obviously an integer that you pass. You probably want to pass `&the_pizzeria->selected_order` instead of `the_pizzeria->selected_order`.

Comment: You never do any checks if a pointer contains `NULL`. That could cause some headache later.

Comment: `get_integer_input( &( the_pizzeria->selected_order ), "");` Fixed... You need to pass the 'address' of the variable, not the value. (Probably want to fill in the prompt string, too, so the user knows what's to be entered.)

Comment: `...without a cast as in my past functions of getting a char input`... It's not `casting`, it is `taking the address of`... You didn't need the `&` for character input because the variable is an `array of characters` (null terminated to become a 'string')... The name of an array is equivalent to taking its address. It is 'C' shorthand for `&arrayName[0]` where the '&' is explicitly shown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show us these "*past functions*", but I assume that they ask the user for name or owner. These elements of your struct are arrays, and if you pass their name as an argument it decays to a pointer to the first element.

In contrast, the integer is not an array. Therefore, you need to pass its address like this:

```c
    if (command[0] == 's') {
        get_integer_input(&the_pizzeria->selected_order, "");
    }
```

If you are not very firm with operator precedence, better use parentheses:

```c
    if (command[0] == 's') {
        get_integer_input(&(the_pizzeria->selected_order), "");
    }
```

The compiler is correct with its diagnostic message. You pass an integer, but the functions needs a pointer.